# Determining which nameserver performed a resolution

Tags: linux, dns, nameservers

I am setting up two nameservers in `constr` and then using `res_search` to find the IP address of a URI.

Is there an easy way to find out which of the two nameservers did the resolution?  I know that I can set up a trace in `res_search` and capture stdout but in my situation that will not be possible.  Is the address of the nameserver somewhere in the result?

Comment: I assume the OP thinks it's meant to be *his* title, rather than the title of the post. Worth an edit, I think...

Comment: I voted to close: "belongs on serverfault.com".

Comment: I agree. The title is strange...

Comment: Voted to reopen...was a little quick on the draw with the close here. This does look programming related after all, just needs to be retagged.

Comment: Voting to reopen - res_search is an API call. I think that's "programming related" by definition.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that I know of to find out which name server returned the result just by looking at the results of a call to `res_search()`.  That information is only in the higher-level UDP packet header and is no longer available by the time the packet has been unpacked by `libresolv`.

However, depending on the version of `libresolv` it appears to be possible to do it by registering a "response hook" with the resolver using:

```
res_send_setrhook()
```

or

```
_res.rhook = &funcptr;
```

The first parameter supplied to the hook callback will be a `struct sockaddr *` of the server that sent the response.  The code below works on MacOS X 10.5.6:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

res_sendhookact hook(const struct sockaddr *ns,
        const u_char *query,
        int querylen,
        u_char *ans,
        int anssiz,
        int *resplen)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "answer returned from %s\n",
            inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)ns)->sin_addr));

    return res_goahead;
}

main() {
    res_init();
    _res.rhook = hook;
    res_search(...);
}
```

BTW it is (mostly) possible to ask a server what it thinks its called:

```
dig @server hostname.bind ch txt
```

which will return a `TXT` record containing the server's hostname (so long as the functionality exists in the DNS server software and hasn't been disabled).

This can be useful to identify which server out of any particular "DNS Anycast Cloud" is serving you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to do a packet trace. From working on a variety of products, I have not seen programers find hooks for logging that kind of information.

Comment: then those programmers haven't looked hard enough ;-)

Comment: Yeah, my familiarity with this is from DNS&BIND, 2nd edition... a bit old. Maybe it is time to minus my answer. Although the packet trace does work. :)